# How to filter objects that have a unique combination of attributes

Tags: javascript, filter, javascript-objects

```
var place =[
 {city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/04/2017", id: 0},
 {city: "Raleigh, NC, United States", begin: "09/11/2017", id: 1},
 {city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/25/2017", id: 2},
 {city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/25/2017", id: 3}
]
```

From the above, I’d like to create a new array that contains objects with only unique city / begin property combinations.  So in terms of the above array, the result would only include the first 3 objects since objects 3 and 4 contain the same city/ begin properties.

I've tried various combinations of the for / if as well as other array methods without success, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a map here.
The key in the map being `city` and the value as an array of `begin`. Then you can filter out the duplicates using this map.

```
var map = new Map;
var len = place.length;
var newArr = [];
for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ){ 
var obj = place[i];
if(map[obj.city] === undefined || map[obj.city] === null){
    map[obj.city] = [];
    map[obj.city].push(obj.begin); 
    newArr.push(obj);
}else if(!map[obj.city].includes(obj.begin)){
    map[obj.city].push(obj.begin); 
    newArr.push(obj);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks -  this solution is perfect - so I can just work from the filtered newArr object.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using the underscore library:

```
var list = [
    { city: 'Durham, NC, United States', begin: '09/04/2017', id: 0 },
    { city: 'Raleigh, NC, United States', begin: '09/11/2017', id: 1 },
    { city: 'Durham, NC, United States', begin: '09/25/2017', id: 2 },
    { city: 'Durham, NC, United States', begin: '09/25/2017', id: 3 },
];

var uniqueList = _.uniq(list, function(v) {
return v.x && v.y;
});

console.log(uniqueList);
```

Comment: No worries, it's from the underscore.js library or you can use the lodash library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and `array#some`. You can store all the unique value in a new object and use it to check if the new object is unique or duplicate of earlier object.

```js
var places =[{city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/04/2017", id: 0},{city: "Raleigh, NC, United States", begin: "09/11/2017", id: 1},{city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/25/2017", id: 2}, {city: "Durham, NC, United States", begin: "09/25/2017", id: 3}];

var uniquePlaces = places.reduce((hash, obj) => {
  let isExist = Object.values(hash).some(v => v.city === obj.city && v.begin === obj.begin);
  return !isExist ? Object.assign(hash, {[obj.id] : obj}) : hash;
}, Object.create(null));

var result = Object.values(uniquePlaces);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```